# JWT token expiration event handler from server using Socket.io?

Tags: authentication, websocket, socket.io, jwt

I'm currently using [JWT](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) to log user in with expiration time of 1 hour `expiresIn: '1h'`. I was wondering if there's a way for the server to inform client right when the token expires (kind of like an event-listener) using [Socket.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io)?

```
const token = jwt.sign(
{
   foo: 'bar',
   random: 'string'
},
'some very long secret',
{ expiresIn: '1h' }) // Will expire after 1h.
```

I was thinking about using `new Date()` or even `setTimeout()` to countdown but I figured those will eventually eat up server memory. If there's any other better method, please suggest me. Thanks.